# How to open a dynamic view in clear case with a given config spects using command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

I have config spects for a view and I need to create a view in Clear Case using command prompt.
Please let me about the commands I can use with some example.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

That would be using:

- [`cleartool mkview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm)
- followed by [`cleartool setcs -tag yourDynView pname`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm), with pname being "a text file whose contents are to become the view's new config spec".

For creating a dynamic view:

```
cleartool mkview -tag yourDynView  \\shared\path\to\viewStorage\yourDynView.vws
```

That will create a dynamic view with a default config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

You will then be able to replace that config spec with any other config spec stored in a file, with the `setcs` command.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply..Can you tell me what should be the directory location for the text file ?

Comment: @savalakh: the text file with the right config spec can be... anywhere you want. Its full path will be the parameter '`pname`' of the '`setcs`' command.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again...
I am not able to mount a vob in it .. I am using base clear case .

Comment: @savalakh can you post in a comment the error message you have when trying to mount a vob?

Comment: @VonC:  in mkview, what is a good location to set your "file whose contents are to become the view's new config spec" to? thanks

Comment: @foampile any path will do, but you don't have to do a `setcs`, you can also go within your view and do a `cleartool edcs`.