# Browsing projects without creating views in ClearTeam Explorer for Rational ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

My company has recently switched from using Perforce to Rational ClearCase for version control.

In the P4Win client it was possible to select View -> Entire Depot and browse depot files that were outside my client spec and this was useful for figuring out exactly what I needed to add to my client spec.

Significantly this avoided the need to synch the files from the depot before viewing them, and was therefore quicker.

I'm now using ClearTeam Explorer and can't seem to find an equivalent. I'd like to have this for a similar purpose, to figure out exactly what I need in the load rules for my snapshot view and also to decide what views I need to create.

**Does anyone know if it is possible to view what files exist under a project in ClearTeam Explorer without first creating a view on the project / joining it?**

ClearTeam Explorer is basically a trimmed down Eclipse with ClearCase specific plugins.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to [create a dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357569/how-to-open-a-dynamic-view-in-clear-case-with-a-given-config-spects-using-comman/9357692#9357692) (you need to add `-stream yourStream@\yourPvob` to the mkview command, I know it looks like you "joining a project", but still, dynamic view are quick to setup).

The idea is to configure your config spec with the right selection rules (a dynamic view will display the files *instantly*), and then make your snapshot view with those same selection rules (and the appropriate load rules, specific to a snapshot view)

---

Note that, according to the [CCRC wiki](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/ccrc/Home):

> With the Release of v8.0, the ClearTeam Explorer is the common Eclipse UI client that supports MVFS on native clients, as well as webviews.
>   CM Server in 7.1.x was renamed to CCRC Wan Server in v8.

If you don't have `cleartool` installed, that means you are using webviews (which are snapshot views with web access to the CCRC Wan server).

In that case, there is no easy way to browse any code from any Baseline (other than joining a project)

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't have cleartool installed so I'm unable to run the make view command at the command line but I can try doing the same thing in ClearTeam Explorer.

Comment: @MikeM_Ireland you don't have cleartool, so that means you are accessing ClearCase through CCRC, right? (ClearCase Remote Client). Ie, you don't have the full ClearCase client installed. Which version do you have?

Comment: That's right. I'm using Rational ClearCase Remote Client 8.0.0. ClearTeam Explorer is also v8.0.0. I looked at creating a new view and noticed that the Dynamic view type option is greyed out. Only web view type can be selected. This may be because I do not have the "native client" installed, since the CTE documentation states:

You must have the native ClearCase client installed on your machine, in addition to the Rational ClearTeam Explorer to use dynamic views.

Is cleartool part of the "native ClearCase client"?

Comment: @MikeM_Ireland yes, cleartool is part of the native client, and dynamic views are too: they are based on a special filesystem (MVFS: Multi-Version FileSystem), which is very tight to the kernel (so local installation mandatory), as opposed to CCRC, which is all about light client and web communication. With CCRC, only snapshot views ("web views") are available.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thank you for all your help! So in summary it is not possible to browse projects that have not been joined when the only tools available are ClearCase Remote Client and ClearTeam Explorer.

Comment: @MikeM_Ireland: yes, CCRC means snashot view only. so no joy here.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW now, wanted to suggest a different solution here.

I would create a web view on the stream with empty load rule.
This will ensure a faster view creation.
Then from ClearTeam Navigator menu, I will enable the options to show

- Unloaded VOBs
- Unloaded Elements

This will ensure that the unloaded elements chosen from my element rules are displayed in ClearTeam Details and ClearTeam Navigator.

**Note**: You need to be connected to the CCRC server to view the unloaded elements.

Then I can browse the file structure and decide which files needs to be added to my view's load rule.

Or I can just right click on any unloaded/partially loaded resource and select *"Load Resource..."* which will load the item to my view.