# cleartool ls: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."

Tags: cleartool

I am trying to use cleartool to browse some CC repositories.  I can get a list of VOBs from lsvob but when I pick a VOB entry, cd into it, and try to do ls . to see what's inside, I get the following error message:

cleartool> ls .
cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."

The following link says I have to be within a view to run ls but how do I know where to go if I can't get a directory listing -- or a view listing to go to.

http://ejostrander.com/cc_errors.html#ERROR19

It seems kind of like you have to already know where you wanna go to and can't get a list of choices.

Question:  How do I go past this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be on Unix in order to be able to do a `cd /vobs/aVobTag`, but that won't give you anything as long as you aren't in a view (or as long as you didn't do a `cleartool setview aViewTag`, which would allows `/vobs/aVobTag` do display anything: see "[ClearCase `setview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview/10252612#10252612)").
Plus those are for dynamic view consultation, which means **you need to mount the Vob first** (`cleartool mount`)

Create a view first, I recommend a dynamic one (easier and quicker to setup: see "[How to open a dynamic view in clear case with a given config specs using command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357569/how-to-open-a-dynamic-view-in-clear-case-with-a-given-config-spects-using-comman/9357692#9357692)" as an example), and go to:

```
cleartool mount /vobs/aVobTag
cd /view/yourView/vobs/aVobTag
```

You will see files there, provided you had checked in files on the `/main` branch, since the default config spec of a Base ClearCase view is `element * /main/LATEST`: see "[Config spec in Rational ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578443/config-spec-in-rational-clearcase/6578525#6578525)".

Comment: can i make a view on the top level of a VOB ?  cause i don't know what's inside of it

Comment: @foampile you are making a view independently of a Vob path: the view root will be `/view/yourView` for dynamic views, or any path for your snapshot view. *Then*, once you have your dynamic view, you mount the vob and can go within it: `cd /view/yourView/vobs/aVobTag`.

Comment: in mkview, what is a good location to set your "file whose contents are to become the view's new config spec" to?  thanks