# ClearCase: How to create Dynamic View through Command Line?

Tags: windows, clearcase, cleartool

Please any body let me know how to create Dynamic View with example with cleartool in windows command line.

Comment: What has this got to do with Python, C++ or Perl? Please keep your tagging to what is *relevant*.

Comment: Hi, Yes its required because so that I can execute the ClearTool command using Python or Perl script.

Comment: Executing a command line tool is trivial from any of those languages, and a **separate** problem. You didn't ask about that in your post, nor do you show a specific problem with any of your attempts.

Comment: Its ok, now you have understood what is my issue, please can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command is [`cleartool mkview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm).

It should be:

```
cleartool mkview -tag yourNewDynamicView -stg aStorageName
# or
cleartool mkview -tag yourNewDynamicView \\shared\path\to\viewStorage\yourDynView.vws
```

You need a storage referencing a shared path in which your view storage will be set, as I showed for instance in "[How to open a dynamic view in clear case with a given config spects using command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357692/6309)".

Comment: Hi VonC, Thanks I will try with your example.